# Should we expand the scope to real-estate questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

The amount of traffic on our site is not growing.  In fact, it has been falling a little every week.  I have been thinking of ways to grow the community, and one option is to expand the scope of the site to related topics.  Since most of us are homeowners, a wider range of questions about [real estate](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8744/real-estate) is one way to grow.

The overlap in community is substantial: many of those who buy homes will then improve and maintain them themselves, and many DIYers will sell their home and buy another in the next few years.

To concretize a little, here are some real-estate–related topics:

- How various improvements affect resale value.  (We have already had [a question about this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/606/electric-fireplace-worth-it).)
- Problems to look for when inspecting a house prior to purchase.
- The economics of buying vs. renting.
- Choosing a real estate agent, inspector, lender, and lawyer when buying or selling.
- Resources to help choose a good neighborhood when moving.
- Moving.

We could also expand into topics related to choosing, [buying](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16587/real-estate-investing), maintaining, and [managing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19379/landlording) residential rental properties.

What do you think—is it a good idea to turn this into a more general home site?

Comment: I'd say your first two bullets are OK for expansion, #4 is questionable, and the rest are too far off DIY to be expansion options.

Comment: I totally agree with Doresoom.  In fact point 4 seems more appropriate for "Personal Finance and Money" (money.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 11):

I'm okay with the real estate questions when they have something to do with home improvement, for example payback on renovations, or house inspections.

However, I don't like the idea of expanding the topic into Real Estate as much as you are suggesting. Some of those things "buying vs renting" just seem too unrelated.

If we must expand the scope, I suggest things that are more related to the maintenance of a house/yard, but might not fall under "home improvement" per se.

For example:
 - Gardening/Lawn care
 - Maintenance of household tools and yard equipment.
 - Pool care and maintenance
 - House Cleaning techniques

Answer (score 5):

I could see the 'Problems to look for when inspecting a house prior to purchase.' being a possible community-wiki thing ... particularly if you qualified them as 'things a DIY-er might be able to fix themselves', or 'an easy fix to try to get the seller to lower the price' vs. 'is going to take bringing in a contractor and a month of not using the property or 'have you ever seen the movie "The Money Pit"?  It's like that'.

Maybe questions of resale value, but that might be a localized thing ... and I'd personally be against the other aspects as I think they're out of scope.